# Physical momentum of phonon

Tags: condensed-matter, momentum, solid-state-physics, crystals, phonons

I have read in the book 'Introduction to solid state physics' by Kittel that phonons do not carry any physical momentum. But what is the reason for phonons not having any physical momentum?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SE. It would be useful for other users to answer your question if you mention the exact reference i.e., in addition to the title of the book and its author's name also the edition and the page number.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is crystal momentum really momentum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/is-crystal-momentum-really-momentum)

Comment: Please post the exact quote with some context; I generally trust Kittel but this statement seems completely untrue in isolation.